# Run application in debug and hit breakpoint by using URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When using MVC if I want to run a test on the "People" function in the home controller I can use a breakpoint at the People function and run the application in debug mode and use the URL in a browser:

```
http:/LH_P/Home/People
```

this stops at the breakpoint. Simple Q I hope but can't seem to get it for ASP.NET application.

So I want to enter a URL that will hit the breakpoint at the TEST() function in the Default.aspx.cs page.

Tried something like: `http://LH:PortNumbner/Default.aspx/Test`

Comment: What's in the `Controller` you can (in general) hit by the URL - you're doing it already. Any other `method` will depend on what's calling it.

Comment: Can you see contents of Default.aspx file when you hit from browser?

Comment: I want to do it in asp.net project, controllers arnt used

Comment: May be you need to enable  Debuggers, select the ASP.NET check box under properties.

Comment: and yes I can see the contents of Default.aspx from browser

Comment: why the minus marks? im stuck on a coding question and thought I would ask the experts

Comment: That's not how debugging works. In MVC, you have a route `/Home/People` that literally references the `People` action in your `HomeController` class, based on the default route. For something like a Web Form page. The URL is only just the page itself, `Default.aspx`. You can't go to a specific function.

Comment: but Im using it as a web request and wanted to test if it was hittin the return function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so what your saying is it is not possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .aspx pages it doesn't work like that. You can't just call a function by using the /FunctionName as you do in MVC. 
You'll need to call the function in the page load method like below.

Run only the first time the page loads:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      Test();
    }
 }
```

Run every time the page loads:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Test();       
 }
```